# Crank-Nicolson method and mixed derivatives

Tags: numerical-analysis, finite-difference, finite-volume

I am curious if anyone had literature references or knowledge on how to apply the Crank-Nicolson (with approximate factorization) to the 
$$
\nabla \cdot (\nu (\nabla \mathbf{u} + \left(\nabla \mathbf{u}\right)^{T}))
$$

What I am unsure about is how to handle the mixed derivative.  Currently I am using Crank-Nicolson for

$$
\nu_{Laminar}\nabla^{2} \mathbf{u}
$$

which is straight forward as I can solve it dimension-by-dimension.

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- usually, Crank--Nicolson specifically refers to a time stepping scheme, but these are stationary problems?

Comment: I agree with @ChristianClason. That said, I think that the OP only wrote the terms of interest, but it should be clarified in the context.

Comment: @Selig5576, what problem exactly are you experiencing with the mixed derivatives?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  When I talk about Crank-Nicholson with approximate factorization, I am talking about applying Crank-Nicholson, but I solve the u_xx, u_yy, u_zz, individually (with TDMA).  What I confused by is since I am using dimensional splitting for my viscous term, how can I calculate the mixed derivative since I am solving directionally.  If it is of any relevance, I have developed a collocated incompressible NS FVM based solver and am interested in studying turbulence with my solver.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you just use CG method, and write a routine that computes Ax, where Ax is your momentum diffusion term. Then just use a matrix free implementation of CG. The only requirement is that A is symmetric positive definite, which I think it is for this case.

Comment: So it is not possible to use an ADI type method for the full viscous stress tensor due to the mixed derivatives?  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm not certain that it is not possible to use an ADI type method, but I'm fairly sure that CG method can be used.